# How can I print only the nth substitution with a single sed invokation?

Tags: sed

I've got this, which *almost* does what I want

```
git show-branch --current 62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274 \
  | sed --quiet --regexp-extended 's/^.*\* \[[a-z]+\/(B-[0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)\].*/\1 \2/p' \
  | sed --quiet 2p #combine this into the previous sed to avoid another pipe/fork
```

and outputs

```
B-47120 java-11-take2
```

`git show-branch` is outputting this

```
! [62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274] B-48141 remove env prefix
 * [ccushing/B-47120-java-10-take1] B-48141 remove env prefix
--
 * [ccushing/B-47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
+* [62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274] B-48141 remove env prefix
```

You'll note that `sed` is piped to `sed`, this is because I only want the 2nd line. I have not figured out a way to combine the `2p` and the expression into a single command. I have tried a variety of things. I get errors like these

```
sed: can't read 2p: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/^.*\* \[[a-z]+\/(B-[0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)\].*/\1 \2/p: No such file or directory
```

I am on **git for windows**, and am limited to tools provided with that.

Comment: So basically you want to only print on the second successful substitution? I suppose standard tools like `tail` or `perl` are not available in the Windows git shell, right?

Comment: @Quasímodo the OP is already using `2p` to print the second line, but that's not the second line of the original input. So we need to print the second line on which the substitution was successful.

Comment: @terdon they are available. I'm just trying to see if it's possible to do this as a single command, instead of piping it to something more. for the little I'm processing tail or perl is probably not any more efficient.

Comment: Could you make the lines different so that it is evident which one should be kept? Maybe change `B-47120` to `B-47121`. Also, you don't seem to explictly mention that you want to keep only the second line for which a substitution was successful: This seems to be the core of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Sed reads each line at a time into the pattern space. The hold space is an additional slot that is initially empty and is only populated when explictly commanded.

To print only the 2nd substituted match,

```
sed -nE '/.*\* \[[a-z]+\/(B-[0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)\].*/{s//\1\2/;x;/./{x;p;q}}'
```

```
/pattern/{        # If the line matches the pattern
  s//replacement/ # Substitute the pattern by the replacement¹
  x               # Swap hold space and pattern space
  /./{            # If the pattern space is not empty, then
    x             # Swap hold space and pattern space
    p             # Print the line
    q             # Quit
  }
}
```

---

To print only the *n*th substituted match (here `n=3`),

```
sed -nE '/pattern/{s//replacement/;H;x;/(.*\n){3}/{s///p;q};x}'
```

```
/pattern/{        # If the line matches the pattern
  s//replacement/ # Substitute the pattern by the replacement¹
  H               # Append a newline and the pattern space to the hold space
  x               # Swap hold space and pattern space
  /(.*\n){3}/{    # If the pattern space contains 3 newline characters²
    s///p         # Delete all up to the last newline¹
    q             # Quit
  }
  x               # Swap hold space and pattern space
}
```

<sup>1: [An empty pattern is the same as the last used pattern](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02).</sup>
<sup>2: Escape parenthesis and braces (i.e., `\(.*\n\)\{3\}`) if not using the `-E` flag.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If we place your sed expression in a variable (without the last `p`):

```
subs='s/^.*\* \[[a-z]+\/(B-[0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)\].*/\1 \2/'
```

And, also, place the `git-branch` output inside another variable:

```
outout='! [62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274] B-48141 remove env prefix
 * [ccushing/B-47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
--
 * [ccushing/B-47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
+* [62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274] B-48141 remove env prefix'
```

We could reduce your command to (assuming GNU sed):

```
printf '%s\n' "$outout" | sed -nE "${subs}p"
```

Now, changing the `p` to `;T;2p` will do what you ask to do (use `;T;2{s/-/ /2g;p}` to replace the dash):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$outout" | sed -nE "${subs};T;2p"
B-47120 java-11-take2
```

Note that the number 2 is addressing the second line from the input, not the second regex match.

If counting matched lines is what is needed, you need to use awk or perl, or two calls to sed (which you already figured out).